# how to keep a textarea in disabled state after form submission?

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have a below code which has a radio button to select between two textareas(textarea1 and textarea2). I am also using a javascript to keep one textarea in disabled state if I select second textarea using radio button.

Below is my html code :

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="emcsaninfo-symcli-main">
<form  id="form1" name="form1" action=" " method="post" > 

<div class="input">select your textarea</div>  
<input onclick="show_textarea_1()" type="radio" name="button" value="Text Area 1" <?php if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Text Area 1')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> />Text Area 1
<input onclick="show_textarea_2()" type="radio" name="button" value="Text Area 2" <?php if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Text Area 2')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> />Text Area 2   

<div id="textarea_1">
<div class="input">Enter your text area 1 message</div>
<div class="response"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" type="text"><?php if(isset($_POST['textarea1'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['textarea1']); }?></textarea></span> </div>
</div>

<div id="textarea_2">
<div class="input">Enter your text area 2 message</div>
<div class="response"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="textarea2" name="textarea2" type="text"><?php if(isset($_POST['textarea2'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['textarea2']); }?></textarea></span> </div>
</div>

<div class="submit">
<input  id="first_submit" type="submit"  name="first_submit" value="first_submit" />
</div>

</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['textarea1']) || !empty($_POST['textarea2'] ) || !empty($_POST['output_textarea'] ) )
{
$textarea1 = $_POST['textarea1'];
$textarea2 = $_POST['textarea2'];

?>


<form  id="form2" name="form2" action=" " method="post" >
<textarea onclick="this.select()" name="output_textarea" id="output_textarea" cols="100" rows="25" readonly value="<?php if(isset($_POST['output_textarea'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['output_textarea']); }?>">
<?php

if(!empty($textarea1)){
echo $textarea1.PHP_EOL;
}

elseif (!empty($textarea2)){
echo $textarea2.PHP_EOL;
}
?>

</textarea>
</form> 

<?php
}
?>

</div>      
</html>
</body>
```

and the javascript to keep the textarea in disabled state:

```
  function show_textarea_1()
   {
    $('#textarea2').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#textarea1').removeAttr("disabled"); 

  }

   function show_textarea_2()
   {

    $('#textarea1').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#textarea2').removeAttr("disabled");
   }
```

After the form submission, I need to keep the disabled text area field in disabled state even after the form submission. How can I do it ?

Comment: how are you submitting the form? full-blown standard submit? then you'll have to rebuild the form with the disabled attribute and send that out with the response. ajax? just leave it disabled...

Comment: `onclick` is not enough, you can unselect a radio button using the the space-bar, a click then would invert the condition. Use `onchange` and check the `.checked` property.

Comment: @ Frits van Campen: thanks, can you give me some more details. will I able to do it after the submit ?